# How in kartik Select2 Yii2 to allow choose any tag entered?

Tags: jquery-select2, yii2

I need to save the entered value of the tag, even if it is not in the list of available database.

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'tagsList')->label(false)->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Tag::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    'options' => [
        'multiple' => true,
        'placeholder' => 'Choose tag ...',
        'tags' => true
    ]
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution:

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'tagsList')->label(false)->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Tag::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    'options' => [
        'multiple' => true,
        'placeholder' => 'Choose tag ...',
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => true
    ]
]); ?>
```